# Cannot modify a matrix element's value with a function

Tags: c, matrix

i'm trying to create a function that sets to 0 the value of every matrix element a[i][j] which is divisible by both i and j. I tried to do it this way but the program just "exits" without giving any error or warning after the  `matrix=editMat(matrix, nrows, ncols);` line.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


FILE *openFileR(const char *);
int rows(FILE *);
int cols(FILE *);
int **readMat(FILE *, int **);
int **allocMat(int, int);
void printMat(int **, int, int);
int **editMat(int, int, int**);

int main()
{
    FILE *fp, *fpout;
    fp=openFileR("matrixmag.txt");
    int nrows=rows(fp); int ncols=cols(fp);
    int **matrix=allocMat(nrows, ncols);
    readMat(fp, matrix);
    printMat(matrix, nrows, ncols);
    matrix=editMat(nrows, ncols, matrix);
    printMat(matrix, nrows, ncols);
    return 0;
}
int **editMat(int nrows, int ncols, int **matrix )
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            if((matrix[i][j])%i==0 && (matrix[i][j])%j==0)
            {
            matrix[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}



int **readMat(FILE *fp, int **matrix)
{
    int value, row, col;

    while(fscanf(fp, "%d %d %d", &value, &row, &col)!=EOF)
    {
        matrix[row][col]=value; 
    }
    return matrix;
}

int **allocMat(int nrows, int ncols)
{
    int **matrix=malloc(nrows*(sizeof(int *)));
    for(int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        matrix[i]=malloc(ncols*sizeof(int));
    }
    return matrix;
}

void printMat(int **matrix, int nrows, int ncols)
{
    for(int i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ", matrix[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

int cols(FILE *fp)
{
    int columns;
    fscanf(fp, "%d", &columns);
    printf("Columns:%d\n", columns);
    return columns;
}

int rows(FILE *fp)
{
    int lines;
    fscanf(fp,"%d", &lines);
    printf("Rows:%d\n", lines);
    return lines;
}

FILE *openFileR(const char *nome_file)
{
    FILE *fp;
    printf("File name: %s\n", nome_file);
    fp=fopen(nome_file, "r");
    if(fp==NULL)
    {
        printf("Couldn't open file\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    else
    printf("File correctly opened\n");
    return fp;
}
```

Input file is

```
3   3
2   0   0
7   0   1
6   0   2 
9   1   0
5   1   1
1   1   2
4   2   0
3   2   1
8   2   2
```

sorry about the errors, i didn't check what i wrote before

Comment: It looks like your `allocMat` function is allocating memory incorrectly. Since matrices are indexed as `[row][column]`, it should be using the `nrows` and `ncols` parameters the other way round when allocating memory: `matrix=malloc(nrows*(sizeof(int *)));` `for(int i=0; i<nrows; i++)` `{` `matrix[i]=malloc(ncols*sizeof(int));` `}`.

Comment: Also, the `matrix` parameter of `allocMat` is useless and should be changed to a variable.

Comment: Please show the first two numbers in the input file, i.e. the number of rows and the number of columns.

Comment: I guess the first two numbers in the file should be 3 and 3. Are those numbers actually there at the start of the file?

Comment: @IanAbbott yes, i just edited it, sorry about that

Comment: @WhozCraig it was a typo, my bad, i changed it to matrix[i][j] = 0 but nothing different happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out i was trying to divide a number by 0, since i and j were both initialized to 0

```
int **editMat(int nrows, int ncols, int **matrix )
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=0; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            if((matrix[i][j])%i==0 && (matrix[i][j])%j==0)
            {
            matrix[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

This way it works fine

```
int **editMat(int nrows, int ncols, int **matrix )
{
    int i, j;
    for(i=1; i<nrows; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<ncols; j++)
        {
            if((matrix[i][j])%i==0 && (matrix[i][j])%j==0)
            {
            matrix[i][j]=0;
            }
        }
    }
    return matrix;
}
```

Thanks everybody for the help anyway :)